# Is there a way to conduct a "fuzzy" search in files in VS 2003?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003, file-search

I need to find code like this:

```
Platypus = true;
```

(that is, any place in the code where Util.StopCancel is set to true)

...but in some places in the code, it is thus:

```
Platypus    = true;
```

(superfluous spaces); thus such cases are not found.

I could just search for "Util.StopCancel" but there are gazillions of references to it (checking the val, mostly), and would like to "sift through the chaff."

Is there a way? I see there's an option to use regular expressions:

[image]

What would be the regular expression for this?

### UPDATE

It's kind of bizarre to me that nobody seems to have a need for this, and thus an answer based on what they already do to find assignments like that.

Comment: What's wrong with regular expressions?

Comment: That's what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Platypus *= *true
```

See [regular expressions for VS2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Of course you won't find anything where value is set from an expression, so better to search for any assignments.